# keypress event in datagrid view?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to write a simple function that when the person enter number of boxes then keypress event fired and `number of boxes*someamount` get in to the amount column. I have added datagridview using drag and drop control

[image]

I think so code will be written here according to my research

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {

}
```

But i dont know how to put Keyup event and access column `numberofboxes and Amount`. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant thanks and how can i get column access

Comment: It is passed to your event handler, e.ColumnIndex property.  Be sure to use the MSDN library to find these kind of answers.

Comment: @Hiri Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tested this and it works by using the key down event and multiples the `NumberBoxes` value by `someAmount`, each time you enter a new number in the cell it does the calculation for you automatically.

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod();
    }


    private void MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod()
    {

        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing +=
    new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress +=
            new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    }

    private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {

            string cellValue = Char.ToString(e.KeyChar);
            //Get the column and row position of the selected cell
            int column = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X;
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y;

            if (column == 1)
            {
            //Gets the value that existings in that cell
            string test = dataGridView1[column, row].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            //combines current key press to the contents of the cell
            test = test + cellValue;
            int intNumberBoxes = Convert.ToInt32(test);
            //Some amount to mutiple the numberboxes by
            int someAmount = 10;
            dataGridView1[column + 1, row].Value = intNumberBoxes * someAmount;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your `dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing` event handler subscribe a new handler to the KeyPress event every time? Which means you'd get more and more duplicate `Control_KeyPress` calls every time you edit another cell. You should probably do `-=` before `+=` or something.

Answer (score 0):

for vb.net

Decimal validation :

```
 Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod()
    End Sub
    Private Sub MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod()
        AddHandler dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing, AddressOf dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing
    End Sub
    Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf Control_KeyPress
    End Sub
    Dim dotOnce As Boolean
    Private Sub Control_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If e.KeyChar Like "[']" Then
            e.Handled = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If e.KeyChar = "." Then
            If dotOnce Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
            dotOnce = True
        Else
           If (Not e.KeyChar Like "[0-9 . ]") Then
                e.Handled = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
          End Sub
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining this code for those who might come along later?